# SEO Search Only content

Tags: seo

We have a ton of content on our website which a user can get to by performing a search on the website. For example, we have data for all Public companies, in the form of individual pages per company. So think like 10,000 pages in total. Now in order to get to these pages, a user needs to search for the company name and from the search results, click on the company name they are interested in.

How would a search bot find this page? There is no page on the website which has links to these 10,000 pages. Think amazon, you need to search for your product and then from the search results, click on the product you are interested in to get to it.

The closest solution I could find was the sitemap.xml, is that it? Anything which doesn't require adding 10,000 links to an xml file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XML sitemap pretty much is your only on-site option if you do not or cannot link to these products on your website. You could link to these pages from other websites but that doesn't seem like a likely scenario.

Adding 10,000 products to an XML sitemap is easy to do. Your sitemap can be dynamic just like your web pages are. Just generate it on the fly when requested like you would a regular web page and include whatever products you want to be found and indexed.

Comment: Appreciate your response and it makes sense, my only hesitation is I looked at a few of Amazon's sitemaps and found URLs to pages which group their products into a single page, such as Black Friday 2014 or Acura TL parts but not individual products. How do you think Amazon does this so their products appear when I search for them on Google?

Comment: That's just because Amazon chooses to promote those pages instead of individual product pages. And even then its hard to use Amazon as an example due to their sheer size. They have tons of links to their product pages and an enormous amount of products. So they probably can't promote them individually but also sort of don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to a page, or for it to be close to the homepage for it to stand a decent chance of getting indexed by Google.

A sitemap helps, sure, but a page still needs to exist in the menu / site structure. A sitemap reference alone does not guarantee a resource will be indexed.

```
Google - Webmaster Support on Sitemaps: "Google doesn't guarantee that we'll crawl or index all of your URLs. However, we use the data in your Sitemap to learn about your site's structure, which will allow us to improve our crawler schedule and do a better job crawling your site in the future. In most cases, webmasters will benefit from Sitemap submission, and in no case will you be penalized for it."
```

If you browse Amazon, it will be possible to find 99% of the products available. Amazon do a lot of interesting stuff in their faceted navigation, you could write a book on it.

Speak to an SEO or a usability / CRO expert - they will be able to tell you what you need to do - which is basically create a user friendly site with categories & links to all your products.